# Jquery: How would I replace n-th Child

Tags: jquery, replace

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <span>SomeContent-->1</span>
  <span>SomeContent-->2</span>
  <span>SomeContent-->3</span>
  <span>SomeContent-->4</span>
  <span>SomeContent-->5</span>
</div>
```

Final result after execution of jQuery:

```
<div id="content">
  <span>OtherContent-->0</span>
  <span>OtherContent-->9</span>
  <span>OtherContent-->8</span>
  <span>OtherContent-->7</span>
  <span>OtherContent-->6</span>
</div>
```

I have stored the `content` element as `var elem = document.getElementById('content')`
Now, I want to replace the children of `elem` by selecting them **One by One**. I tried to use the function `.replaceWith()` but didn't work for me Is there any other way?

Comment: I can't tell from your question if you are using jQuery somewhere else or if you are confusing jQuery and javascript. Just in case, jQuery is a javascript library. The element stored in `var elem = document.getElementById('content');` is not using jQuery. If you were to select that same element with jQuery, it would look like $("#content").replaceWith()

Comment: @tom
Well ok.. But, I can always to this:
`var elem = $(this)`
Can't I?

Comment: You can use `var elem = $(this)` as long as you are inside of a function where `this` references something. But you can do `var elem = $("#content");` or `$(elem).replaceWith`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use .html() or .text()

```
 $('span', elem).text(function(index, currentValue){ // or use .html for html content
      return "new value";
  });
```

or

```
  $('span', elem).each(function(){
        this.innerHTML = "newContent"; // or $(this).text('newContent') / $(this).html(newContent)
  });
```

- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [.eq(n)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

For replacing nth element's content use:

```
$('span', elem).eq(n).html(newCOntent); // or .text() where n is 0 indexed.
```

Comment: Suppose I have stores element with the class `content` in some variable. Then, how would I do it, using that variable?

Comment: What do you mean by `stores element with the class content` can you elaborate.

Comment: Like `var elem = document.getElementById('content')`. Now< i want to work with `elem` and not like this `$('#content span')`

Comment: Ok in that case `$(elem).find('span')` or `$('span', elem)`

Comment: Ok now last question. How to find `3rd` or `4th` or `nth child` using this method?

Comment: You want to select 3rd, 4th or want to see in the loop?

Comment: `$('span', elem).eq(3)` will give you 4th element `$('span', elem).eq(0)` will give you 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :eq selector with span, like following

```
    $('#content span:eq(1)').text('<text>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like like..

```
$('#content span').each(function(i, span){$(span).html('OtherContent-->0')})
```