# Replace every nth class name and replace it with the help of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replace every 6th div class.

This is my current code

```
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div> this should be change
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div> this should be change
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div> this should be change
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
```

It's unlimited and undefined count because its changes in every section

Comment: Do you want content replacement or the whole div replacement

Comment: [similar to this...check if it is helpful for you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183060/jquery-how-would-i-replace-n-th-child

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$( "div:nth-child(6n)" ).removeClass("disp");
```

Or

```
$( "div.disp:nth-child(6n)" ).removeClass("disp");
```

Comment: `$('.disp:nth-child(6n)').text('ddd')` - a class selector(`.disp`) instead of the element selector(`div`) will be better suited

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div> 
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div> 
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
<div class="disp">...</div>
```

Doing this with pure css

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    margin:10px;
}

section > div:nth-child(6n) {
    background:red;
}
```

Here can also do this with jquery

```
 $( "div:nth-child(6n)" ).removeClass("disp");
```

For more refrence follow this link [Style every third element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860786/style-every-third-element)